# Guidelines in using Ajax in a Grid Table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, zend-framework

This is a very basic and probably a stupid question. But I am fairly new to programming and your answers would help me a lot.

I have a simple grid table as shown in the image below.

[image]

Every record in the grid has basic operations like view, edit, update, duplicate and delete. And there are two ways of implementing these operations, I can implement without using AJAX or I can use AJAX and perform these operations. But I am confused on what should I use.

Most of the websites and system that I have seen don't implement AJAX at all and some of them implement AJAX for few operations like view, delete and for other like insert, update they don't.

My question is are there any particular guidelines in using AJAX in such situation? What would be the best thing to do here?

My project is based on Zend Framework 1.12, PHP 5.4 and MySQL I would appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: A table like yours seems a natural for an AJAX REST interface. Also, there are JS frameworks and libraries that already supply everything except the actual endpoints PHP side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ajax is using Javascript to perform operations. If your clients will be using javascript, using Ajax could avoid unnecessary page reload and will improve user experience.

Nevertheless, using Ajax can be a bit more complex than using only PHP.

If you can go Ajax, and do it properly, I would suggest you to go with it.